# Delicious API - All bookmarks for a given website?

Tags: json, api, rss, bookmarks, delicious-api

Is there a way for me to get at a list of the URLs on my website which people have bookmarked on the delicious.com website? Their documentation appears to make no reference to wildcard searches or anything other than individual URLs.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delicious.com provides [feeds](http://delicious.com/help/feeds) to query information about URLs, but the function only accept an md5 hash of the URL you want to look up.  It looks like it's impossible to perform a single query with a wildcard search via the currently exposed public API.  A hack would be to create a list of of valid URLs of your site and then query Delicious for each of these URLs keeping in mind the [inter-request delay of 1-second](http://delicious.com/help/api) as well as other restrictions.

Comment: Absolutely, that mirrors my own conclusions at this time.

Comment: Did anybody come up with a better solution so far? Doing several request to the api does not feel so good, imho.